# Importing images into DataBase

Tags: android, image, sqlite

in my app I use SqLite Database "Templates", where I have table "favourites", constains of four columns "id", "description", "imagePath", "category". I would like user to be able use their own images in my app, like this:
When user click button, he choose image from gallery, write description and choose category of image. I know I need use Content Values to do this. But how can I do my table has imagePathes, i.e how can I show them later using RecyclerView and Picasso?

Comment: After user select an image, you get the image-uri/path, you can obtain that image and create a copy into you app-specific directory (android/data/<package-name>/) or somewhere (it will enable you to use that image even after user deletes it from their original direcotry). Then you can store your own app-specific path into Database.

Comment: Yes, I think it will work. But I am just beginner, so could you sent me links how I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load image from device memory:

```
Picasso.get().load(new File("path-to-you-image/image.png")).into(imageView);
```

If you are asking "how to get image path" - you can get it in the onActivityResult method:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
        filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();
```